# Define a TypeScript type based on an object?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define a type based on an instance of an object?

I don't want to define an interface first, I want a generic type that takes a value as the input, not a type.

Example:

```
const someObject: any = {
  foo: "",
  bar: ""
}

// should show error because "bar" property is missing
const someOtherObject: SameShape<someObject> {
  foo: ""
}
```

A flat object structure is all I need at the moment. So something like this (except something that works):

```
type SameShape = { [key in keyof someObject]: string }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typeof` operator.

```
// This is valid
const someOtherObject: SameShape<typeof someObject> 

type SameShape<T> = { [key in keyof T]: string }
```

But you need to remove that `any` in `someObject: any` first.

Now for you use case, following is enough, you don't need an extra `SameShape`

```
const someOtherObject: typeof someObject = {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Why not directly `const someOtherObject: typeof someObject`? It's not clear if types should be preserved or not since only string is used.